# Setting up has_many through correctly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many-through

Yesterday I asked a question about setting up has_and_belongs_to_many relationships between models in Rails. I eventually got those relationships working, however, I realized that I needed to store additional information in my join table, which means I should be using a has_many through relationship with a join model (I presume?).

I now have a Recipe model, Ingredient model, and an Amounts join model. Each Recipe has many Ingredients and vice versa. And each Ingredient in a recipe has a certain Amount in a certain unit type.

Here is my setup so far:

models/recipe.rb

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :amounts
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :amounts
end
```

models/ingredient.rb

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :amounts
  has_many :recipes, :through => :amounts
end
```

models/amounts.rb

```
class Amounts < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipes
  belongs_to :ingredients
end
```

MySQL tables:

```
$ mysql > show columns from recipes;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| desc       | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| image_url  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> show columns from ingredients;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> show columns from amounts;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| recipe_id     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ingredient_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| amount        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| units         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I think I have the relationships set up correctly...I'm just unsure about how to add to the join model/table correctly and then access those values. For instance, will I be able to call @recipe.ingredients and return all the ingredients associated?

**EDIT:**
I apologize for the confusion over what I am trying to do.

When I was using the has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, I could push to @recipe.ingredients with '<<' and have the join table automatically inserted with the recipe_id and ingredient_id. However, this method doesn't seem to work when using has_many through because of the additional attributes in the join table.

How would I go about creating these associations?

Comment: This looks good to me. What problems are you having?

Comment: I think I'm confused about how I create the associations the right way. I have a Create Recipe form where ingredients can be chosen that should be associated with that Recipe. When using has_and_belongs_to_many, I could loop through the selected Ingredients and add each with this line: @recipe.ingredients << ingredient.

I don't think that method works with this however, since there is now a join model. I'm not sure how to add them the right way.

Answer (score 0):

you can read and assign to `recipe.ingredients` directly and it will automatically write to the join table.

But unlikely you will need it since you need additional info for the amount. You probably will need to update/create recipes with nested attributes for amounts coming from a form.

consider a uniqueness contraint on ingredients per recipe in amount model.

hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a `has_many :through` association is some of that Rails magic. You'll have access to all the methods that the `has_many` association sets up for both the join table, and the related table. Rails will take care of any associations automatically.

Have a look at the Rails guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference).

Comment: Is there a particular way to create the associations when I'm actually adding values to the Recipes and Ingredients tables? Do I have to create the Amount model manually and then assign values to @recipe.ingredients?

Before, when I was using has_and_belongs_to_many, I could just use the '<<' operator and the association was created automatically, but that method doesn't seem to work with the has_many :through.

Comment: Here is how I am attempting to create the association between created Recipes and Ingredients: https://gist.github.com/2820294

I am getting "uninitialized constant Recipe::Amount" as the error when I submit the form.

Comment: Can you also put the application trace in?

Comment: On second glance, I think it looks like your form logic may be slightly off. Can you also put the view code and the associated controller action?

Comment: App Trace: 
`app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:57:in 'block in create'
app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:56:in 'create'`

Gist for view: https://gist.github.com/2820374
Gist for show in controller: https://gist.github.com/2820378

Comment: That's not the form view code. Your problem is with the new view and create action, not the association. Open up a new question with this

Comment: add the link to the new question please.